# Check a value in *ngIf which is passed from component

Tags: angular, data-binding, components, angular-ng-if

I am passing a value from component like this

```
<component1 [height]="900"></component1>
```

of course value declared in .ts file as

```
@Input() height:number=0;
```

binding to div like this

```
<div style="height:{{height }}px;" ></div>
```

I will use this in another component like this

```
<component1 [height]="300"></component1>
```

Now, I'm having trouble using the *ngIf condition to determine whether the div height is bigger than zero.

```
<div style="height:{{height }}px;" *ngIf___________ ></div>
```

How any suggestions.

If I check the value *ngIf="{{height}}>0" the Angular application will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell that one of your problems is the syntax.
You have to delete curly braces on the `*ngIf` statement:

```
<div *ngIf="height > 0"></div>
```

EDIT:
You will have to properly bind value to component as well.
To bind a variable to a component you will have to do the following :

```
<component1 [height]="900"></component1>
```

Also, you can checkout angular directives for css [style](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) and [class](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) binding